# Android NFC: Intent when detect any type of NFC

Tags: android, nfc

I'm triying to detect when a NFC tag is readed. This code works, but it doesn't for a Mifare Classic tag. Mi smartphone is not compatible with this tech but I have installed an app (NFC Tools) that is able to detect when a Mifare Classic tag is near. It can't read the stored data, but I don't need it. I just need to detect the event. This thrid-party app is able to do it, so I'm sure that is possible but I don't know how.

This is my code:

```
private void prepareIntent() {
        mAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        if (hasNfcCapabilities()) {
            mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    this, 0, new Intent(this, ((Object) this).getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
            IntentFilter techDiscovered = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED);
            IntentFilter tagDiscovered = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED);
            IntentFilter ndefDiscovered = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
            try {
                techDiscovered.addDataType("*/*");
                tagDiscovered.addDataType("*/*");
                ndefDiscovered.addDataType("*/*");
            } catch (IntentFilter.MalformedMimeTypeException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mFilters = new IntentFilter[]{techDiscovered, tagDiscovered, ndefDiscovered};
            mTechLists = new String[][]{};
        }
    }
```

What have I to do to detect Mifare Classic tags?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Documentation says:

[enter link description here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#enableForegroundDispatch(android.app.Activity,%20android.app.PendingIntent,%20android.content.IntentFilter[],%20java.lang.String[][]))

> filters   the IntentFilters to override dispatching for, or null to always dispatch

So, passing `null` in filters parameter in method `enableForegroundDispatch` of `NfcAdapter` it will detect all type of NFC tags.

`mAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, mPendingIntent, null, mTechLists);`